# How to view Images in Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm starting to do a little game for Android.
Recently I did have a reading where the user touches the screen;)
I would like on the basis of these data, moving image.
Displays an image in the XML (**imageView**). What to write **java code** to move at that image?
I would like to rotate the image, move it anywhere on the phone screen or remove it.
How something is done?
I am interested in java code only because I know what to do in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you read [through this series of tutorials](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) to get you started with drawing graphics on Android for games.

Comment: +1 awesome tutorial series didn't know about that one yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out the Animation classes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html , RotateAnimation, TranslateAnimation etc... they're really easy to use and can be very powerful.

If you setFillAfter to true and setFillEnabled to true then the result of the animation is permanent.